# Save File unresponsive for Website Dialog in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, popups, save-as, dialog

*Skip to the last paragraph for the question.*

I have the following issue:

An application opens a webpage dialog window to assist with some workflow. At some point I want to open a preview, click a button and the file-download pop-up appears (so far so good). The problem now is the the webpage-dialog windows seems always to be in front of the pop-up, so I cannot choose any option. As soon as I close the dialog window, I can choose from the "Open", Save As..." etc. options. But this is bad, since I now canceled my workflow.

Hope this image clears the issue up a little.
[image]

**So my questions comes down to the following point:**
Can I force either the dialog-window to be behind the download pop up, or force the pop up to be in front of every other element on the site via my browser settings?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, this isn't a programming question. I just wanted to know if there is a browser setting to change the layering of the windos/pop-ups.

Comment: No there isn't. Your application needs to change the way it opens dialogs (always on top or something). That is a programming issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill, Then your comment would be a valid answer to my question. That isn't my application, I was just asking from a user point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @DavidPostill

> No there isn't. Your application needs to change the way it opens dialogs (always on top or something). That is a programming issue.

Since it isn't my application this problem isn't solvable.